# Why does adding GROUP BY cause a seemingly unrelated error?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following code works fine:

```sql
SELECT name, (SELECT count(item_id) FROM bids WHERE item_id = items.id)
FROM items;
```

However, when I add

```sql
SELECT name, (SELECT count(item_id) FROM bids WHERE item_id = items.id)
FROM items
GROUP BY name;
```

I get `ERROR:  subquery uses ungrouped column "items.id" from outer query`

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: In your second query, should the semi-colon in the second line be there?

Comment: No, just edited. Thanks for catching.

Comment: Because you're using a non-aggregate value for the correlated subquery. A group has multiple values and it can't know which one to use.

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear, your subquery is essentially grouped by `item_id`, and the outer query by `name`, which doesn't match and makes little sense. Why not just `join` the tables, it'll make a much simpler query.

Answer (score 1):

If you `GROUP BY name` then any other columns you select from `items` must have an aggregate function applied.  That's what `GROUP BY` means.

In your case, you are using another column from `items` -- `id` -- in a correlated scalar subquery.  That's not an aggregate function, and `id` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause, so you get an error.

You could instead `GROUP BY name, id`.  That should give you the same results as the first query, and is probably pointless.

If you actually have multiple rows in `items` with the same value for `name`, and you want to group the results of the scalar subquery for those values, you need to specify how to group them.  Perhaps you want the total of the subquery results for each value of `name`.  If so, I think you could do:

```
SELECT name, SUM(SELECT count(item_id) FROM bids WHERE item_id = items.id))
FROM items
GROUP BY name;
```

(I'm not positive about the specific syntax as I don't have a Postgres instance to test against.)

A clearer way to express it might be:

```
SELECT name, SUM(bid_count)
FROM (
SELECT name, (SELECT count(item_id) FROM bids WHERE item_id = items.id) AS bid_count
FROM items
)
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables then perform the GROUP BY:

```
select i.name, count(b.item_id)
  from items i
  inner join bids b
    on b.item_id = i.id
  group by i.name
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3df1dc5d3ce18e6e10f022062d545f94)